# How to enable tablayout in only some fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have this layout in the app_bar_main.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/collapse"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="256dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

       <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

where I enable/disable the collapsingToolbarLayout with interface.

The problem is when I want to use the TabLayout in a nested fragment.
In fact, if I try to do is:

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_parking, container,false);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

I get a NullPointerException, because in my layout of the nested fragment I have only the viewPager:

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="436dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>



</RelativeLayout>
```

so how could I enable/disable the tabLayout in only some nested fragment? I must put it in the layout of fragments or I could ability it in activity?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tableLayout is in the activity layout but you search in fragment layout to find it.
add this inside fragments onCreateView() and remove other code :

```
((YourActivity)getActivity()).tabLayout.setVisibility(View.Gone|View.Visible);
```

And tabLayout most be public object in activty

Comment: enjoy coding !!